# how to convert factor levels to integer in r

Tags: r

I have following dataframe in R

```
  ID      Season      Year       Weekday
  1       Winter      2017       Monday
  2       Winter      2018       Tuesday
  3       Summer      2017       Monday
  4       Summer      2018       Wednsday
```

I want to convert these factor levels to integer,following is my desired dataframe

```
  ID      Season      Year       Weekday
  1       1           1          1
  2       1           2          2
  3       2           1          1
  4       2           2          3

  Winter = 1,Summer =2
  2017 = 1 , 2018 = 2
  Monday = 1,Tuesday = 2,Wednesday = 3
```

Currently, I am doing `ifelse` for above 3

```
  otest_xgb$Weekday <- as.integer(ifelse(otest_xgb$Weekday == "Monday",1,
                                   ifelse(otest_xgb$Weekday == "Tuesday",2,
                                          ifelse(otest_xgb$Weekday == "Wednesday",3,
                                                 ifelse(otest_xgb$Weekday == "Thursday",4,5)))))
```

Is there any way to avoid writing long `ifelse` ?

Comment: I would not recommend directly converting the `Weekday` column as it will lexicographically provide values when converted to integer or numeric. For eg. `Wednesday will get a higher value than `Saturday` and `Tuesday`. Setting its values directly using `levels` function would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `match` with `unique` elements

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
      mutate_all(funs(match(., unique(.))))
#   ID Season Year Weekday
#1  1      1    1       1
#2  2      1    2       2
#3  3      2    1       1
#4  4      2    2       3
```

Answer (score 3):

```
m=dat
> m[]=lapply(dat,function(x)as.integer(factor(x,unique(x))))
> m
  ID Season Year Weekday
1  1      1    1       1
2  2      1    2       2
3  3      2    1       1
4  4      2    2       3
```

Comment: I would not recommend directly converting the `Weekday` column as it will lexicographically provide values when converted to integer or numeric.For eg. `wednesday` will get a higher value than `saturday` and `tuesday`. Setting its values directly using levels function would be better.

Answer (score 3):

***Ordered and Nominal factor variables are needed to be taken care of separately***. Directly converting a factor column to integer or numeric will provide values in ***lexicographical*** sense.

Here `Weekday` is conceptually *ordinal*, `Year` is *integer*, `Season` is generally *nominal*. However, this is again subjective depending on the kind of analysis required.

***For eg.*** *When you directly convert from factor to integer variables. In `Weekday` column, `Wednesday` will get a higher value than both Saturday and Tuesday*:

```
 dat[] <- lapply(dat, function(x)as.integer(factor(x)))
 dat 

#  ID Season Year Weekday
#1  1      2    1       1
#2  2      2    2       3
#3  3      1    1       2   (Saturday)
#4  4      1    2       4   (Wednesday): assigned value greater than that ofSaturday
```

Therefore, you can convert directly from factor to integers for `Season` and `Year` columns only. *It might be noted that for `year` column, it works fine as the lexicographical sense matches with its ordinal sense.*

```
dat[c('Season', 'Year')] <- lapply(dat[c('Season', 'Year')], 
                                   function(x) as.integer(factor(x)))
```

`Weekday` needs to converted from an **ordered factor variable with desired order of levels.** It might be harmless if doing general *aggregation*, but will ***drastically affect results when implementing statistical models***.

```
dat$Weekday <- as.integer(factor(dat$Weekday, 
                          levels = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", 
                                     "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"), ordered = TRUE))

dat
#  ID Season Year Weekday
#1  1      2    1       1
#2  2      2    2       2
#3  3      1    1       6  (Saturday)
#4  4      1    2       3  (Wednesday): assigned value less than that of Saturday
```

***Data Used:***

```
dat <- read.table(text="  ID      Season      Year       Weekday
1       Winter      2017       Monday
2       Winter      2018       Tuesday
3       Summer      2017       Saturday
4       Summer      2018       Wednesday", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `as.numeric()` to convert a factor to a numeric. Each value will be changed to the corresponding integer that that factor level represents:

```
library(dplyr)

### Change factor levels to the levels you specified
otest_xgb$Season  <- factor(otest_xgb$Season , levels = c("Winter", "Summer"))
otest_xgb$Year    <- factor(otest_xgb$Year   , levels = c(2017, 2018))
otest_xgb$Weekday <- factor(otest_xgb$Weekday, levels = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"))

otest_xgb %>% 
  dplyr::mutate_at(c("Season", "Year", "Weekday"), as.numeric)


# ID Season Year Weekday
# 1  1      1    1       1
# 2  2      1    2       2
# 3  3      2    1       1
# 4  4      2    2      NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have converted the season, year and weekday to factors, use this code to change to dummy indicator variables

```
contrasts(factor(dat$season) 
contrasts(factor(dat$year)
contrasts(factor(dat$weekday)
```